# How to setup Dagger with ViewModel and Saved State Getting ''getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory' overrides nothing' error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I'm using latest Dagger and latest AndroidX libs with Compose. I want to inject SaveStateHandler for my Activity and Compose, So i tried as mentioned on this article, but  I'm getting below error on my Activity now,

```
kotlinVersion = '1.7.21'
daggerVersion = '2.42'
appCompatVersion = '1.5.1'
lifecycle-viewmodel = '2.5.1'

'getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory' overrides nothing
```

My Setup is Like this

```
       interface AssistedSavedStateViewModelFactory<T : ViewModel> {
                    fun create(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): T
                }
            
            
                @Reusable
                class InjectingSavedStateViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
                    private val assistedFactories: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards AssistedSavedStateViewModelFactory<out ViewModel>>
                ) {
                    fun create(
                        owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
                        defaultArgs: Bundle? = null
                    ): AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory {
                        return object : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {
                
                            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
                                key: String,
                                modelClass: Class<T>,
                                handle: SavedStateHandle
                            ): T {
                                // Attempt to get ViewModel from assisted inject factories
                                assistedFactories[modelClass]?.let {
                                    try {
                                        return it.create(handle) as T
                                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                                        throw RuntimeException(e)
                                    }
                                } ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown model class $modelClass")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

// ViewModelModule

```
@Module
            abstract class ViewModelModule {
            
                @Binds
                @IntoMap
                @ViewModelKey(AccountViewModel::class)
                abstract fun bindVMFactory(f: AccountViewModel.Factory): AssistedSavedStateViewModelFactory<out ViewModel>
            
            }
```

// ViewModel

```
 class AccountViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
            private val resourcesSurface: ResourcesSurface,
            private val analyticsComponent: AnalyticsComponent,
            private val appConfig: AppConfig,
            @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
        ) : ViewModel() {
        
        
            @AssistedFactory
            interface Factory : AssistedSavedStateViewModelFactory<AccountViewModel> {
                override fun create(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): AccountViewModel
            }
        
        }
```

//I'm getting error on Activity

```
    class AccountActivity : BaseActivity() {
    
    
    
        @Inject
        lateinit var abstractViewModelFactory: dagger.Lazy<InjectingSavedStateViewModelFactory>
    
  // ERRROR on this method "override nothing"
        override fun getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory =
            abstractViewModelFactory.get().create(this)
    
        private val viewModel: AccountViewModel by viewModels()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            viewModel.getMenuItems()
    
            setContent {
    
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: nope, instead i used the dagger Assisted injection and pass the value as constructor arguments to viewModel